# HelpViewer memory leak & Screen Time statistics

Tags: screen-time, memory-leak

There appears to be a memory leak with HelpViewer in OS Ventura 13.1 on a Mac with an M1 chip.

That's bad in general, but it also means that my Screen Time usage statistics are thrown off because it shows that I'm running the app 24 hours a day:

[image: graph of screen time usage]

Any suggestions for dealing with this?